# netty tcp communication using load balancer(L4).how can i handle config?

Tags: apache-camel, netty

As i am a novice of netty .here is my problem.

client side made of netty4 tcp communication and server module created by apache camel netty.

and in the middle of this communication,we have a load balancer L4.

this is our picture.

[client and server picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMiKk.png)

client config :10.10.10.1:8501

server config :

from (10.10.10.1:8501....

from (10.10.10.1:8502....

how can i make a client config file?

Comment: Its unclear what you question is, and especially what a client config file is. You say you use Netty on the client, I assume there is no usage of Apache Camel there. So its more a Netty question that a Camel question. Netty is just a library so how to make a client file is confusing, as it depends how you have build the client application and how it runs etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you can set your two address in your client, justo do it:

```
.loadBalance().roundRobin().to(ExchangePattern.InOut, "address1", "address2")
```

But I didn't understand about your config file, for me you are talking about properties, right?

If you are talking about properties you can take ir in your routeBuilder with a Properties, like this:

```
Properties property = new Properties();
property.load(new FileInputStream("YourProperties.properties"));
String propA = property.getProperty("propA");
```

Or set it in your blueprint/spring and get it in your route.
Here you can find more explanations about it
http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html